# Find the three nearest and biggest numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For a personal project I need to find the index of the three nearest and biggest numbers in an array, but I cannot find an algorithm to do that.

For example, if the array is:

```
[1 2 3 59 70]
```

the output should be

```
[0 1 2]
```

Or if the array is:

```
[3 6 7 49 50 51 79 81 100]
```

the output should be

```
[3 4 5]
```

Someone has an idea? Thanks in advance for the help!

**Edit:**

- Yes, we can assume that the input is sorted.
- Sorry for being unclear, but "nearest" means that the difference between the three numbers must be minimal.
- The important thing is that the three numbers have the minimal absolute difference. When I have two triplet with the same absolute difference, I take the biggest one, i.e. the one with the maximal sum(triplet).

Comment: I didn't get it. How do the exemples generalize? What are "nearest and biggest"?

Comment: We can assume the inputs are sorted?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you want to find the index of the integers with minimum difference, you could simply loop through the array and check the difference `a[i+1] - a[i]` , `a[i+2] - a[i+1]` , etc...

Comment: Why do you output three indexes? Does this mean the array is not sorted?

Comment: @G.Bach In this case the difference between the numbers is the same, but I consider [43, 46, 49] bigger, because the sum(first_array) is greater than sum(second_array).

Comment: @Henry The array can be considered sorted. I output the three indexes because I need them, insead of simply having the three numbers.

Comment: If the array is sorted, the 3 numbers are always in successive positions so one index would suffice.

Comment: It isn't clear how the numbers could be both nearest and biggest. Is "biggest" only used to break ties? It also isn't clear what exactly the "difference between three numbers" means. By the way, your second example isn't sorted.

Comment: @asf107 Yes, I can do that if I need the difference between two numbers, but with three numbers your solution doesn't work. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @interjay I hope that the new edit clarify how I want to use "biggest". Moreover, now the array is sorted, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just linearly walk through the array and check the differences. If you find equal differences, update the current solution:

```
minDistance = arr[2] - arr[0]
minIndex = 0
for i from 3 to n - 1
    if(arr[i] - arr[i - 2] <= minDistance)
        minIndex = i - 2
        minDistance = arr[i] - arr[i - 2]
return { minIndex, minIndex + 1, minIndex + 2 }
```

Comment: [C++ Implementation of Nico's solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a5ddea0e91325d)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!